# What is the meaning for the phrase 'your tone doesn't inspire me to be very forthcoming'?

Tags: verbs

The phrase from the movie 'House of cards'

context:

Newspaperwoman wanted the man (Underwood) to tell her some info, therefore, she hurries him. And the man (Underwood) told her these words (your tone doesn't inspire me **to be very forthcoming**)

question:

> 1) I don't get his message (to be very forthcoming is about her or about her tone)
>
> 2) I like this way of using of 'to be'. Could you give me some extra examples with such using of 'to be' verb for conclusive understanding

Thanks

Comment: Her tone of voice makes him feel  reluctant to divulge much information.

Answer (score 2):

We can be in a certain mental state with respect to doing something.

> I am eager to go.
>
> I am reluctant to go.

Something can put us into such a state.

> Her tone made me eager to go.
>
> The danger made me reluctant to go.

Here,  with an adjective as complement of **to be**:

> Her tone caused me to be eager to go.
>
> The danger caused me to be reluctant to go.

**made me** and **caused me** license different complements. **made** in modern English does not license an object complement with an infinitive at its head, whereas **caused** does.

We can express that same idea using a noun:

> Her tone awoke in me an *eagerness* to go.
>
> The danger awoke in me a *reluctance* to go.